# Optimal algorithm to find exit of a maze with no information

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, maze

I have to determine a way for a robot to get out of a maze. The thing is that the layout of the maze is unknown, and the position of the exit is unknown too. The robot also start at an unknown position in the maze.
I found 3 solutions but I have a hard time knowing which one should I use, because in the end it seems that the solutions will purely be random anyway. 
I have those 3 solutions :
1) The basic "human" strategy(?), where you put your hand on a wall and go through all the maze if necessary. I also keep a variable "turn counter" to avoid situation where the robot loop.
2) Depth first search
3) Making the robot choose direction randomly

The random one seems the worse, because he could take forever to find the exit (but on the other hand he could be the fastest too...). I'm not sure about the other two though.
Also, is there a way to have some kind of heuristic? Again the lack of information makes me think that it's impossible, but maybe I'm missing something.

Last thing : When the robot find the exit, he will have to go back to his start position using A*. This means that during the first part, where he looks for the exit, he will have draw a map of the maze that he will use for the 2nd part. Maybe this can help too chose the best algorithm for the first part, but yeah I don't see why one would be better.

Could someone help me please? Thanks (Also, sorry for my english).

Comment: The first two solutions are identical, and both are guaranteed to find the exit (assuming the graph is connected). The random solution is not guaranteed to find an exit.

Comment: Indeed, seems you're right. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems like this are categorised as real-time search, perhaps the best known example is Learning Real-Time A*, where you combine information about what you've seen before (if you've had to backtrack or know a cheaper way to reach a state), and the actions you can take.  As is the case in areas like [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit), some level of randomness helps balance exploration and exploitation.

Assuming your graph is undirected, time invariant, and the initial and exit node exist in the same component, then choosing  a direction at random at each vertex is equivalent to a [random walk on a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Random_walk_on_graphs). 
Regardless of whether the graph is initially known or not, this is a very well understood field of mathematics, equivalent to an [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain), the time to reach the exit state in such cases has a [Discrete phase-type distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_phase-type_distribution) - often quite slow, but it's also worth noting that in pathological cases it's possible to design a maze where a random walk will outperform DFS.

Answer (score 0):

@beaker is right in that the first two you suggested should lead the the same result.  However, you may be able to improve on the search a little by keeping track of any loops you find. If the Robot finds itself in a spot it has already visited and needs to backtrack once coming to a dead end there may be no need go back so far if there is a shortcut it has found. Also use the segments that have been mapped on the way out and apply Dijkstra's algorithm or A* on it to find the most efficient way back. There may be a faster way back on an unexplored path but this would be the safest way to have a quick result.

Obviously this implementing the checks for loops to prevent unneeded back tracking will make thing more complicated to implement. Though for the return to the start using Dijkstra's algorithm should not be as complex.

If you are feeling ambitious now that found the exit you could use this information and give the robot a sense of direction though in a randomly generated maze that may not help much.

Comment: I see, I will try that optimization if I have the time then.

Comment: If you find this answer acceptable please accept it to help close the question. or upvote it is it have been helpful (same for beakers comment)

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work