# How to find optimal solution of a maze with limited information

Tags: java, algorithm, search, maze

I've been looking for an optimal, efficient algorithm in Java that will walk to the exit of a maze (4-directional movement), given only 3 pieces of information:

1. Our current location and current Manhattan distance to exit
2. Traversable tiles adjacent to current location, and their Manhattan distances to exit

We do NOT know the exact location of the exit, only how far we (and our neighboring tiles) are from it.

We CANNOT access neighbors of neighbors, or neighbors of any other node that we are not currently standing on.

We access our current location, distance from the exit, and our neighboring NodeDatas from State s. Each node has a long ID associated with it.

NodeDatas are Comparable and thus sortable by their distances to the exit.

My current algorithm is a somewhat-optimized greedy depth first walk of the maze, which is acceptably efficient but is often thrown off by tiles that seem "closer" to the exit but don't actually lead to it. I was wondering if there was any further steps I could take to optimize the algorithm, or perhaps supplant it with some sort of A*.

```
    private boolean smartDFS(SeekState s) {
    long u= s.currentLocation();
    FibonacciHeap<Long> toVisit= new FibonacciHeap<>();
    if (s.distanceToRing() == 0) return true;
    visited.add(u);
    for (NodeStatus w : s.neighbors()) {
        long wID= w.getId();
        if (!visited.contains(wID)) {
            toVisit.enqueue(wID, w.getDistanceToRing());
        }
    }
    while (!toVisit.isEmpty()) {
        long wID= toVisit.dequeueMin().getValue();
        s.moveTo(wID);
        if (smartDFS(s)) return true;
        s.moveTo(u);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've read this thread on an apparently similar issue: [Optimal algorithm to find exit of a maze with no information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175098/optimal-algorithm-to-find-exit-of-a-maze-with-no-information), but the answer isn't concrete enough for me to understand.

The mazes in my problem are not perfect (they have multiple solutions). My program runs via a GUI, but an example of a maze, where 1's are walls, periods are paths, and X is the goal would be:

```
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
.  .  1  .  1  .  .  1  1  1  1  1
1  .  1  .  .  .  .  1  1  1  1  1
1  .  1  1  .  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1  1  1
1  1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  .  1  1
1  .  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  .  X  1
1  .  1  .  .  .  .  1  1  .  .  1
1  .  .  .  1  1  1  1  1  .  .  1
1  .  1  .  .  .  1  1  1  .  .  1
1  .  1  .  1  .  1  1  1  .  .  1
1  .  1  .  1  .  1  .  .  1  .  1
1  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

To be extra clear, here is how my game is structured:

My traversal algorithm has access to a game state State s. State s contains the following functions:

```
// returns the id of current location
long currentLocation();

// returns NodeData of current neighbors
Collection<NodeData> neighbors();

// returns current distance to exit
int distanceToExit();

// moves player to node with the specified id
void moveTo(long id);
```

Instances of NodeData, which are Comparable, contain information about a node, namely;

```
long getId();

int getDistancetoExit();

// compareTo() and equals() are also implemented.
```

Complexity is almost a non-concern, and anything in O(n!) time is probably fine. What I want to minimize is the number of total steps I take.

Comment: Could you give a small sample maze, just to make sure we interpret your problem correctly?

Comment: @DillonDavis Edited post to include sample maze.

Comment: This sounds like a setup for [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: @beaker I tried implementing A* search, which as far as I know involves “choosing” a node with the lowest f-score in an openList — but ran into the difficulty of not being able to get the neighbors of that node. (Recall how I can only get the neighbors of the very node I stand on.)

Comment: Those are the only neighbors you need.

Comment: So should my A* simply move my character to the node with the lowest f-score? How do I implement an A* that uses the neighbors of my current location without picking out a node and then enumerating its neighbors?

Comment: @beaker With A* you need information about more than one node to choose the next node to explore. You have a priority queue of all unexplored nodes ordered by shortest estimated distance to the goal. In OP's setup, you can't simultaneously stand on all of these nodes at once, you only have information about 1 node

Comment: @inordirection To clarify, at any given point in the maze I have information on up to 5 nodes -- the one I am standing on and up to 4 that I can walk to from there. I can also store all this this information throughout my walk. Does that change my circumstance at all?

Comment: @inordirection Ah, yes. If you must commit to a move in order to check its neighbors and cannot backtrack, then you cannot guarantee any approach will give you the optimal solution.

Comment: @KevinWengJr. Yeah, in that case you actually could do A* as you could theoretically maintain its priority queue of estimated distances for the open nodes, but for any node you pop from the queue you would have to backtrack to it before you could expand/explore it. There would be a lot of overhead involved in shuffling back and forth between nodes in the frontier like that, storing/maintaining the information that would allow you to do so. So you could get the optimal path with A* here, but the overhead would make the complexity for finding it with A* quite bad.

Comment: @KevinWengJr. I think you would probably be better with a kind of heuristically guided DFS, where you just have to maintain the current path you've taken and a visited set, and then at every iteration recurse on the unvisited neighbor with the lowest manhattan distance to the goal (rather than iterating over neighbors and recursing on them in arbitrary order). If you ever reach a node with no unexplored neighbors and you need to backtrack, you could use/pop the path you've built to backtrack up the DFS tree until you find a node with an unexplored neighbor again.

Comment: @KevinWengJr. This sort of approach wouldn't give you the guaranteed optimal solution but it would run a lot faster than A* because of its much simpler backtracking, and would most likely be quicker and more optimal than naive DFS as well,

Comment: @KevinWengJr. If strict optimality is really important though, then you could try to store alongside every node in A*'s frontier/priority queue the path you could take to get back to it from your current location, and update all these paths every time you make a move so that when you pop from the queue the node with the lowest f(n), you know how to backtrack to it from your current location because of its stored path. I think that could be pretty hard to implement though.

Comment: @inordirection Great, thanks for the ideas! I tried to implement a sort of heuristically guided DFS as you suggested, shown in the updated post. It's certainly much better than the unguided DFS, but I would like to pursue further optimality. I'm wondering if A* would be possible here

Comment: @inordirection So I think I've settled on a heuristic-based recursive DFS, particularly one that uses the same heuristic as A*: the sum of current node's distance to exit and current node's distance to start. This is apparently referred to in https://www.aaai.org/Papers/JAIR/Vol21/JAIR-2119.pdf as "A*DFS". But I don't know how to go about saving the distances from the current node to the starting node, especially since 1. my method is recursive and 2. at any given game state I only have access to my own node and its neighbors.

Comment: Your dfs would need a visited set though, right? And a current path which it could use to backtrack and which it would return once it finds the goal node? These could just be parameters to the dfs function of course. I think that you could use the length of the current path as your g(n), but since you're always making a choice between the neighbors of one node and they all would have g(n) = currentPath.length + 1, I don't think the g(n) could actually influence your decision as it would be the same for every node you're choosing between.

Comment: Maybe the A*DFS the paper is referencing is calculating g(n) not just as the length of the current path walked, but as an absolute distance from the start node to the current position. So you could use euclidean distance there instead of path length, but I'm not sure that would actually help for optimality since you mainly care about path-length